# Boolean with python exact string match

Tags: python

I want to select articles based on the Boolean condition as

```
(unemployment OR inflation) AND (covid19 OR uncertain) AND (tax OR spending OR bank)
```

I am looking to do it by exact string matching. I have given below codes below. The problem with the current code is that it gets me words as, taxes, taxable, taxpayers for the word "tax" Thanks in advance!!

```
df = data[['date', 'title', 'body_text']]

def wordestimaor(X):
  
    df['count'] = X.body_text.str.contains("covid19|uncertain")\
     & X.body_text.str.contains("unemployment|inflation")\
     & X.body_text.str.contains("|tax|spending|bank",case = False,regex= True) 
         return X.head(2)
wordestimaor(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to write it with spaces on left and right, so it will find only full words (like instead of "covid19" you need to write " covid19 ").

But sometimes it can't work, like in this situation: "covid19," (with comma). You need to check these variants too. To do that, a function can be very useful.

```py
symbols = [' ', ',', ';', '!', '?', '.']

def find_word(word):
    for smb in symbols:
        if X.body_text.str.contains(' ' + word + smb):
             return true
    return false
```

Edit: If the word is standing in the beginning of a sentence, it will start with a capital letter. So you can also check it.

Comment: Yeap I just tried but I found it missing some of the original variables.